# Opencart 1.5.6.4 vqmod not writing

Tags: permissions, opencart

Does anyone know of any issue with vqmod on opencart version 1.5.6.4? It is not writing to the vqcache folder as it should and I have checked permissions and groups. This is a duplicate and newer version of an opencart site on the same folder running 1.5.5.1. The permissions are the same and vqmod is writing just fine on the older version. I also deleted vqmod alltogether and installed the latest version again.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the issue was that I had my live site in public_html and my test site in /public_html/test and I forgot to include /test in the config.php paths.